# How do i target my old website from .NET 4.5.1 to 4.5.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an old website, it is not web application so there is no properties window to target the .NET Framework to 4.5.2, how do I modify the web.config to target .NET Framework 4.5.2?

I need to know that it uses .NET 4.5.2 because I want to test whether the application is compatible with it before deploying to production

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the web project and select the Application tab on the left.  There is an option for Target Framework:  It will probably be set to 4.5 or 4.5.1.  Change it to 4.5.2 and repeat for any other projects in the solution.